# Getting coordinates in Projected Coordinate System using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have map built using the ArcGIS API for Javascript 4.8. The basemap is the ESRI "streets" basemap in wkid 102100 (latestWkid 3857).

How do I get the coordinates in the following to be output as wkid 2810 (NAD_1983_HARN_StatePlane_Minnesota_North)?

Here's the code:

```
mapView.on("pointer-move", function(event){
    console.log(mapView.toMap(event));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot transform the reference system from a basemap. 
You have 2 possibilities, either to use a Custom Basemap in wkid 2810 or insert your layer with different coordinate systems (this will affect the performance)